# Change image during scroll when the text becomes visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrolltop

I have this script that changes the image(s) when the `text` reaches the top of the screen. I want it in reverse. I would like to have the image(s) change when the `text` becomes visible from a certain height (say 50px) from bottom. How do I go about this?

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ramo427e/

HTML:

```
<div class="main">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h1>This is sparta and what comes whatever after. This is sparta and what comes whatever after. This is sparta and what comes whatever after. </h1><h1>This is sparta and what comes whatever after. This is sparta and what comes whatever after. This is sparta and what comes whatever after. </h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <section id="one">
                        <div class="content">
                            <h1>first heading</h1>
                            <p>description</p>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                    <section id="two">
                        <div class="content">
                            <h1>second heading</h1>
                            <p>description</p>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                    <section id="three">
                        <div class="content">
                            <h1>third heading</h1>
                            <p>description</p>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                    <section id="four">
                        <div class="content">
                            <h1>fourth heading</h1>
                            <p>description</p>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="image"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <h1>This is sparta and what comes whatever after. This is sparta and what comes whatever after. This is sparta and what comes whatever after. </h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
*{
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}
h1{
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: strong;
}
p{
  font-size: 12px;
}
.main{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    position: relative;
}
.image {
    background-image:url('https://i.postimg.cc/FRxNp6yG/hr-ax.png');
    background-size:100% 100%;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    transition: 1000ms;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: fixed;
}
#one, #two, #three, #four {
    min-height: 150px;
}
```

JS:

```
$(window).on("scroll touchmove", function() {
            if ($(document).scrollTop() >= $("#one").position().top && $(document).scrollTop() < $("#two").position().top) {
                $('.image').css('background-image', 'url(https://i.postimg.cc/FRxNp6yG/hr-ax.png)')
            };
            if ($(document).scrollTop() >= $("#two").position().top && $(document).scrollTop() < $("#three").position().top) {
                $('.image').css('background-image', 'url(https://i.postimg.cc/wvz9hzm7/hr-bx.png)')
            };
            if ($(document).scrollTop() >= $("#three").position().top && $(document).scrollTop() < $("#four").position().top) {
                $('.image').css('background-image', 'url(https://i.postimg.cc/FRxNp6yG/hr-ax.png)')
            };
            if ($(document).scrollTop() >= $("#four").position().top) {
                $('.image').css('background-image', 'url(https://i.postimg.cc/wvz9hzm7/hr-bx.png)')
            };
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

on the scroll, you can get the position of the all element. And calculate whether it is visible or not. Based on the switch case you can change image.

Sample:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    var element = document.querySelector('#main-container');
    var position = element.getBoundingClientRect();

    // checking whether fully visible
    if(position.top >= 0 && position.bottom <= window.innerHeight) {
        console.log('Element is fully visible in screen');
    }

    // checking for partial visibility
    if(position.top < window.innerHeight && position.bottom >= 0) {
        console.log('Element is partially visible in screen');
    }
});
```

More:

https://usefulangle.com/post/113/javascript-detecting-element-visible-during-scroll

Comment: Could you show a working demo? I couldn't get this to work with different class/ids.

Answer (score 0):

Select the text with jQuery and correct the height relative to that and use that to trigger the event for Example:

```
if($(document).scrollTop() >= $("#one .content h1").position().top - 50){
   $('.image').css('background-image', 'url(https://i.postimg.cc/FRxNp6yG/hr-ax.png)')
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this just measures the top minus 50? https://jsfiddle.net/jfnez38x/ I want it from the bottom of the screen when it becomes visible on scroll.

Comment: @ElaineByene Maybe I misunderstood your question, maybe you can clarify your question a little bit more (by image and marker when a image should be visible). So the idea is that you have to compare top of the document scroll and top of an element relative to that (you can not use bottom or something like that, if you need bottom of some block you have to put some invisible element in the bottom or get the height of the element and subtract that form the top)